# Passing data from gridview button to modal window

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, modal-dialog

I am trying to pass data from a button within a gridview to a modal window. I need to pass the ID of the record in order to be able to reference it after submitting the form within the modal window.

I am struggling with this quite a bit. First I need to be able to pass the ID variable to the modal, and then upon clicking the submit button make an ajax call to create a new record within the DB.

The Gridview

```
if(isset($results)){
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
        'id'=>'searchgrid',
        'fixedHeader' => true,
        'headerOffset' => 40, // 40px is the height of the main navigation at bootstrap
        'type'=>'condensed',
        'dataProvider'=>$results,
        'responsiveTable' => true,
        'template'=>"{items}",
        'columns'=>array(
            array('name'=>'title', 'header'=>'Name'),
            array('name'=>'city', 'header'=>'City'),
            array('name'=>'state', 'header'=>'State'),
            array('name'=>'leads', 'header'=>'Leads', 'value'=>'Parkslist::model()->leadRange($data["leads"])'),
            array('name'=>'pastbid', 'header'=>'Previous', 'value'=>'Parkslist::model()->pastBid($data["pasthighbid"])'),
            array('name'=>'currentbid', 'header'=>'Current', 'value'=>'Parkslist::model()->highBid($data["currenthighbid"], $data["secondhighbid"], $data["countcurrenthighbid"])'),
            array('name'=>'minimumbid', 'header'=>'Minimum', 'value'=>'Parkslist::model()->minimumBid($data["currenthighbid"], $data["secondhighbid"], $data["countcurrenthighbid"])'),
            array('name'=>'userhighbid', 'header'=>'Your Bid'),
            array('name'=>'placebid', 'header'=>'Bid', 'value'=>'CHtml::textField("bid" . $data["id"])', 'type'=>'raw'),
            array('name'=>'report', 'header'=>'Report',
                'value'=>function($data){
                    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                        'label' => 'Click me',
                        'type' => 'primary',
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => '#myModal',
                            'data-id' => '$data["id"]',
                        ),
                    ));
                }
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

The Modal

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id' => 'myModal')); ?>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h4>Why should this park be removed?</h4>
    </div>
    <form>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <select>
            <option>Duplicate</option>
            <option>Closed</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type' => 'primary',
        'buttonType'=>'submit',
        'label' => 'Save changes',
        'url' => '#',
        'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
    )); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label' => 'Close',
        'url' => '#',
        'htmlOptions' => array('data-dismiss' => 'modal'),
    )); ?>
    </div>
    </form>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. I would assume there might be a better solution but this seems to work.

First, inside of the button in the gridview I made the button ID = to the id of the record. Next, I created a javascript function called includeData and included the button ID.

Button Code

```
array('name'=>'report', 'header'=>'Report',
                'value'=>function($data){
                    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                        'label' => 'Click me',
                        'type' => 'primary',
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'id'=>$data["id"],
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => '#myModal',
                            'data-id' => '$data["id"]',
                            'onClick' => 'includeData(this.id);'
                        ),
                    ));
                }
            ),
```

JS Code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function includeData(parkid){
        $('#reportparkid').val(parkid);

}
</script>
```

The JS function just sets the value of a hidden field equal to the buttonid. I would love to see some better ways to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: I also have similar situation like you. Can you please tell me how can I use reportparkid inside modal-body.